# Android button with transparent text

Tags: java, android, android-button, android-shape

I have a button on an image. I would like to have this button with a solid background color and transparent text (to display the back image). Is it possible to make it have only transparent text?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding these attributes to your Button:

```
android:textColor="@android:color/transparent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
```

Answer (score 1):

By transparent do you mean like partially visible. Also look into the image button instead of assigning the background image to a button.

Comment: I don't think the ImageButton is what they're going for. The way they've described it, they want the button to only cover *part* of the image, and have the text on the button be transparent so the image behind it can be seen.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it may be a use case for an ImageButton. It allows specifying an Image and a background. Notice the src and background tags, txt is not required.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageBtn"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_large_len"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_large_len"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_play"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_gray" >
</ImageButton>
```